# unable to build Android project using Facebook SDK against Android 2.2 (Froyo)

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I've recently started getting into programming with the Facebook SDK for Android, which I used to write a basic sample app. I want it to be able to run on as many systems as possible, so I set the build target to Android 2.2 (Froyo/API level 8). However, this results in the following error:

```
Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 8   FacebookTestApp
```

In comparison, all of the sample apps that came with the Facebook SDK have their build target set to Android 2.2, and none of them have this problem. Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When/where do you get the error?

Comment: Could you also give the API settings of your application (minimum, build, target)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem today, this is how I fixed it:

Righ click on your project > properties > Java compiler > enable "project specific settings"
Set Compiler compliance level to 1.6
re Build your project

Voila!

Answer (score 5):

`Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); currently using API 8`

Here is the solution:

`Right click your project -> Properties -> Android ->` Select the lasted `Project Build Target`

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Right click on your project > Android Tools > Fix Project Properties.

Refresh the project and clean+build it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Project -> Clean... -> Clean all projects
```

Fixed this for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can build with API level 19 and still define minimum API level to 8.